# How load specific web pages on my android application?

Tags: android, webview, android-internet

Please don't minus my question if it is wrong i am new on android.
I want in my application have a connection to about us of my site. means when press a button open about us of my site and show information of that.
How should implement it?

Comment: You will need a WebView: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you should have an activity that embed a webview. In the onclick of your button, you have to launch it.

```
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUrl);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
          }
```

In the webview class

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

    }
```

Normally it will do what you want.